# Prevent direct access to website on primary domain with multi-domain hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting

I recently purchased multi-domain hosting and hosted several domains on my plan. The other domains are hosting on subfolders in my primary domain. So when I go to `www.secondarydomain.com` it will display the website located at `www.primarydomain.com/secondarydomain`.

Now what I want to do is prevent direct access when someone tries to access `www.primarydomain.com/secondarydomain` whilst keeping www.secondarydomain.com alive.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.primarydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^\s\?]+)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1.com [R=302,L]
```

Once you make sure it is working fine change 302 to 301.

PS: Keep in mind that it will redirect every URL like `http://www.primarydomain.com/foo` with a physical directory `foo` to `http://www.foo.com`.

#### EDIT - To avoid matching certain known folders use negative lookahead like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.primarydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^\s\?]+)
RewriteRule ^(?!(foo|bar|baz)/).*$ http://www.%1.com [R=302,L]
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the working example. How can I modify this to make exclusions for certain folders?

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Pls check my EDIT section now.

Comment: I actually had a problem with this - the htaccess file did start conflicting with the other hosted domains after a few days, most stopped working! so I had to delete the htaccess file. I spoke to my hosting company and they told me if I don't have a htaccess file in the subfolder it will imply the conditions of the htaccess file in the parent folder.

Comment: There are ways to avoid execution of this .htaccess in subfolders but I would suggest you to first post your current .htaccess in your question and provide little more details on what actually stopped working.

Comment: I'm sorry I've made a mistake, your code was fine, i just couldn't get it to work how I wanted it so I used a HTACCESS generator and made some conflicting redirects which messed up everything. Some domains were not resolving and one was working was redirecting from www.thedomain.com to www.thedomain.com/subfolder-name (where subfolder-name was the hosted folder i.e. `root/subfolder/wwwroot`

Answer (score 1):

I know that in IIS, you can set rules so that if someone comes in at www.primarydomain.com/secondarydomain, you can redirect them to www.secondarydomain.com.  It is a basic pattern match that you look for, and if it resolves to "true", it will redirect as you tell it.

If you don't want www.primarydomain.com/secondarydomain to work at all, you can do the same thing, except redirect to an error page instead.  I'm sure apache and other servers have similar functionality, but I have only dealth with it in IIS.  It's called URL Rewrite and Redirect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wouldn't that create an endless loop though? Accessing the secondarydomain.com name redirects to my hosting (primarydomain/subfolder) and the primary domain redirects to the secondarydomain.com

Comment: No that's not what I meant.  You would redirect only from primarydomain/subfolder to your secondarydomain.com.  You wouldn't redirect the opposite way.

Comment: Oh no, I just thought that when the domain name resolved and it connected to my server, the mod_rewrite would take place - but thats not the case since the htaccess is in the root folder not in the subfolder